# Swift/Xcode: How to make Firebase observer functions action while app is in background?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, push-notification, observers, unusernotificationcenter, unusernotification

**WORKING IN SWIFT/XCODE**
I have a messaging app with observers connected to Firebase. When a new messages comes into Firebase, I want the app to send a local push notification to the iPhone.

Currently, when a new message comes in and the app is in the foreground, the notification is firing. However, when the app is in the background, the observer/notification are not firing. How do I make the notifications continue when the app is in the background?

Comment: You can't.  Use a push notification to wake up your app process to check for changes.

Comment: So how do all other chats apps send push notifications when users get a new message? What is the easiest way to implement that?